# Openlayers map projection not working while saving the features into PostGis

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wms, wfs, wfs-t

In my web map application, I have added the wfs vector layer for feature editing. There is no issue When I save the feature in postgis after editing. But when I refresh the wfs layer, its showing the edited portion in somewhere. See the below image

[image]

Here is my code:

```
function init(){ 
format = 'image/png';

bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds(
                -288161.9289062237, -435.65815425360597,
                949406.755566389, 1300000
            );
var options = {
    controls: [],
    maxExtent: bounds,
    maxResolution: 5079.826789665053,
    projection: "EPSG:404000",
    units: 'm'
};

osMap = new OpenLayers.Map('map', options)

//Setup Base layer
tiled = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                "Oxford_Map", "http://xxx.xx.x.xx:8080/geoserver/cite/wms",
                {
                    LAYERS: 'Oxford_Map',
                    STYLES: '',
                    format: format,
                    tiled: true,
                    tilesOrigin: osMap.maxExtent.left + ',' + osMap.maxExtent.bottom
                },
                {                        
                    buffer: 0,
                    displayOutsideMaxExtent: true,
                    isBaseLayer: true,
                    yx: { 'EPSG:404000': false }
                }                  
            );

untiled = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                "Oxford_Map", "http://xxx.xx.x.xx:8080/geoserver/cite/wms",
                {
                    LAYERS: 'Oxford_Map',
                    STYLES: '',
                    format: format
                },
                {                        
                    singleTile: true,
                    ratio: 1,
                    isBaseLayer: true,
                    yx: { 'EPSG:404000': false }
                }                    
            );

 osMap.addLayers([untiled, tiled]);

   graphicsWFSlayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Graphics Data", {
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],       
    projection: osMap.projection,        //EPSG:404000
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
        version: '1.1.0',
        url: 'http://xxx.xxx.x.xx:8080/geoserver/wfs',
        featurePrefix: 'cite',
        featureNS: 'http://www.opengeospatial.net/cite',
        maxExtent: osMap.getExtent,
        featureType: 'ODC_Private_Graphics_Data',
        geometryName: 'the_geom',
        extractAttributes: true,            
        srsName: osMap.projection,  //EPSG:404000
        isBaseLayer: false,
        visibility: true,
        schema: 'http://xxx.xxx.x.xx:8080/geoserver/wfs/DescribeFeatureType?version=1.1.0&;typename=cite:ODC_Private_Graphics_Data'            
    })
});

osMap.addLayers([graphicsWFSlayer]);
 }

 // This function will be called when we click save icon on map web page.

 function saveFeature(){
 var selFeat = graphicsWFSlayer.selectedfeatures[0];
 var featCoordinates = '';
 var geoType = selFeat.geometry.CLASS_NAME.split('.');
 var vertices = selFeat.geometry.getVertices();
 for (var nd = 0; nd < vertices.length; nd++) {
     if (featCoordinates == '') {
          featCoordinates = vertices[nd].y + " " + vertices[nd].x
     }
     else {
         featCoordinates += ', ' + vertices[nd].y + " " + vertices[nd].x
     }
 }
 if (selFeat.geometry.CLASS_NAME == 'OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon' && vertices.length > 2) {
     featCoordinates += ', ' + vertices[0].y + " " + vertices[0].x
     featCoordinates = '(' + featCoordinates + ')';
 }            
 WebService.saveGraphicsFeature(keyId, featCoordinates);
}

//My webservice function is:
  <WebMethod(enablesession:=True)> _
  Public Function saveGraphicsFeature(ByVal ObjId As String, ByVal coordinates As      String) As String
    Try
   If updateGraphicsFeature(ObjId, coordinates) = False Then
            Dim qryStr As String = "INSERT INTO ODC_Private_Graphics_Data (the_geom)    VALUES (ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON(" + coordinates + ")'))"
            dbObj.Connect()
            Dim insertCmd As NpgsqlCommand = New NpgsqlCommand(qryStr, dbObj.dbCon)
            Dim affectedRows As Integer = insertCmd.ExecuteNonQuery
            dbObj.Disconnect()
            insertCmd.Dispose()
            insertCmd = Nothing
   End if
    Catch ex As Exception

    Finally
        dbObj.Disconnect()
    End Try
End Function

 Private Function updateGraphicsFeature(ByVal ObjId As String, ByVal coordinates As   String) As Boolean

    Try

        Dim qryStr As String = "UPDATE ODC_Private_Graphics_Data SET the_geom =    ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON(" + coordinates + ")') WHERE gid = " & ObjId

        dbObj.Connect()
        Dim updateCmd As NpgsqlCommand = New NpgsqlCommand(qryStr, dbObj.dbCon)
        Dim updatedRows As Integer = updateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery
        dbObj.Disconnect()
        updateCmd.Dispose()
        updateCmd = Nothing

        If updatedRows = 1 Then Return True

        Return False

    Catch ex As Exception

    Finally
        dbObj.Disconnect()
    End Try
End Function
```

Please help me to fix this issue. did i miss any step in my code? or Should I set projection anywhere?

Comment: Why don't you use GeoServer WFS-T http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/geoext/wfs/wfst.html instead of reinventing the wheel on your server side?
You will limit problems by reducing your own custom code (not a critic, just the less custom code you do the more you avoid trouble)

Comment: Yes I tried that method. But I have problem in that method as well.Please see my post regarding this http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76259/problem-with-wfs-t-save-strategy-in-openlayers  and give me your valuable solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're incorrectly capturing the eastings/northings (x/y) components of your coordinates in your *saveFeature* javascript function:
e.g.

```
featCoordinates = vertices[nd].y + " " + vertices[nd].x
```

I think should be

```
featCoordinates = vertices[nd].x + " " + vertices[nd].y
```