# Geometry sent to PostGIS is null

Tags: postgis, geoserver

I am writing simple PostGIS trigger function that takes NEW.the_geom value from GeoServer and puts it in a table. But the value in a table stays NULL.

I was wondering in what form GeoServer sends geometry data to PostGIS database.

Is it standard geometry crypted content or GeoJSON visible text?

Comment: How are you requesting the data from geoserver?

Comment: see "configure a WFS in geoserver using PostGis as a data store" https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/118160/276

Comment: Actually, I don't know. I don't even work with Geoserver. All I do is to write trigger functions for PostGIS database which is further used by my collegue working with Geoserver and OpenLayers...

Comment: I get all object features with NEW record, except geom feature. If I try: SELECT St_X(NEW.geom) into mywar; then mywar stays NULL

Comment: turn logging  on GeoServer up to GEOTOOLS-DEVELOPER and you will see the exact query sent to PostGIS. I think it uses standard WKB encoding for the geometry